# Python dataframe loc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Why is that `df.loc[df[‘xx’] ==‘yy’,’oo’].values` turns out to be a blank list/array （array([],dtype=float64)）instead of returning a 0 in a dataframe? when I call out df, that specific spot shows 0, which is changed by myself from a `nan`.

I want the `loc` spot appears to be 0 which it’s supposed to

Comment: Could you add a short example of your data? Preferably also the actual output + expected output

Comment: It returns array([],dtype=float64)     I want it to return a 0

Answer (score 0):

The `df.loc[df[‘xx’] == ‘yy’, ’oo’].values` result, contains filtered data that match by this condition, if you want **count** of matched rows you must use `count` method, same as below:

```
df.loc[df[‘xx’] == ‘yy’, ’oo’].count()
```